# When $2^{2n}-2^{m+2} + 4$ is a square number?

Tags: number-theory

The question is for which values of $m,n\in \mathbb{N} $ the number $2^{2n}-2^{m+2} + 4 $ is a square number. I've obtained that if $m=n$ then $2^{2n}-2^{n+2} + 4 = (2^n - 2 )^2$ and I think (but I'm not sure) that if $m\neq n$ then it's not a square number.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Depending on the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ in use: it's always a square for $m = 0$, so that may or may not count.

Comment: Thanks. In this case is for $n,m \geq 1 $

Comment: Also, $m = 2n-2$. Generally, suppose it is a square, say $(2^n - k)^2$, find conditions on $k$.

Comment: But $(2^n - k )^2 = 2^{2n} - k\cdot 2^{n+1} +k^2 $ and this is equal to $2^{2n}-2^{m+2} + 4 $ if and only if $k=2$. And also I don't understand why in the general case the square root has the form $2^n - k$

Thanks Fischer!